# .NET 6 Function App - how to return a HTML page from a file

Tags: c#, html, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I'm currently in the process of migrating several Azure Function Apps to .NET 6. One of these involves returning various content files via a HTTP request.

Previously (on .NET 3.1) this works fine for both json/text files, and HTML:

```
var callbackFileLocation = Path.Combine(Helper.GetFunctionPath(), "Files", filename);

var stream = new FileStream(callbackFileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
{
    Position = 0
};

var okObjectResult = new OkObjectResult(stream);

okObjectResult.ContentTypes.Clear();

if (filename.Contains(".html"))
{
    okObjectResult.ContentTypes.Add(new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
}
else
{
    okObjectResult.ContentTypes.Add(new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
}

return okObjectResult;
```

This doesn't return the same results on .NET Core 6 - you tend to just get given the object type as a name e.g. *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult* or *System.IO.FileStream*. It's easy enough to fix for the json files, as I can just convert them into text, and make sure the function app is returning that as the payload.

HTML seems trickier - I've tried reading the stream to end, and various methods mentioned here and on other sites, e.g:

```
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(string filename)
{
    var callbackFileLocation = Path.Combine(Helper.GetFunctionPath(), "Files", filename);
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var stream = new FileStream(callbackFileLocation, FileMode.Open);
    response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
    return response;
}
```

Or returning the HTML text within FileContentResult ("application/octet-stream") or ContentResult, e.g:

```
new ContentResult { Content = content, ContentType = "text/html", StatusCode = 200 };
```

The closest I've got is the HTML as raw text, but want the HTML rendered in the browser.

Any suggestions? Documentation around this on .NET 6 seems thin...thanks!

Comment: `return Content("<h1>Test</h1>","text/html; charset=utf-8");` works for me. It gets properly rendered as html in the browser.

Comment: Hmm, I created a new function app, and although I couldn't get your code to work, this would render             var html = "<html><body><p>Test</p></body></html>";
            var result = new ContentResult
            {
                Content = html,
                ContentType = "text/html"
            };

            return result;

BUT this was still using webjobs rather than the new Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker

Comment: What was the problem implementing my code? Because your code is basically the same as mine :D But you got it working now?

Comment: Content() is part of MVC, it's not part of Function Apps by default. I've converted the function from an isolated to standard, and can get it to render HTML now. The lack of info from Microsoft about these changes has been a real PITA.

Comment: Oh of course. Sorry I forgot that. My bad. But nice that you got it to work now. And yes the docs are not the best right now :D

Answer (score 1):

Got to work for **dotnet-isolated** by looking at the Azure Function with HTTP Trigger example file that can be generated using VS Studio

```html
  var response = httpRequestData.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
  response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");

  response.WriteString("<html><body>Hello <b>World</b></body></html>");

  return response;
```

Where httpRequestData is of type HttpRequestData and the Function should return HttpResponseData

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer (and thanks for the help @Jonas Weinhardt) - but I couldn't find a way to do this using **dotnet-isolated** process.

It worked fine when moved back to non-isolated. (I guess it's something to do with the new GRPC functions or something like that?)